# return char from std::string vector

Tags: c++, string, c++11, popen

How do you pass popen data?
I have a script I use but when ever I try and bring the data into another function, I get a conversion error -> deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' because popen want to be in standard char.

code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

FILE *init( char *fname ){
        FILE *fp = popen( fname, "r" );
        return fp;
}

char getmarketbuyData(FILE *fp){
        char buff[BUFSIZ];
        vector<std::string> vrecords;
        while(std::fgets(buff, sizeof buff, fp) != NULL){
                size_t n = std::strlen( buff );
                if ( n && buff[n-1] == '\n' ) buff[n-1] = '\0';
                if ( buff[0] != '\0' ) vrecords.push_back( buff );
        }
        for(int t = 0; t < vrecords.size(); ++t){
                cout << vrecords[t] << " " << endl;
        }
                return 0;
}

int main(void){
        FILE *fp = NULL;
        fp = init("/usr/bin/php getMyorders.php 155");
        if (fp == NULL) perror ("Error opening file");
        if ( fp )
                getmarketbuyData( fp );
}
```

error:

# g++ -g returnFileP.cpp -o returnFileP.o -std=gnu++11
returnFileP.cpp: In function 'int main()':
returnFileP.cpp:29:66: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

How do I properly pass/return popen data to another function?

Comment: If you aren't modifying `fname`, make it `const`. Don't force the users of that function to work around your lack of const-correctness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an error when calling `init` in `main`. The string literal `"/usr/bin/php getMyorders.php 155"` has type `const char *` and call to init requires an implicit conversion to `char *`. Such conversion (for string literals) was allowed, but it's now deprecated.

`popen`'s first argument has type `const char *`, so I don't see a reason why should `init` require a non-const parameter. Declare it as

```
FILE *init( const char *fname )
```

to get rid of warnings.